# Display Button on Form (Continuous) Depending on record

Tags: ms-access

I have a list of Records that I am Displaying in a continuous form. I am also putting buttons in this form.

IE
I have a list of "exams" on the list I have buttons for each exam such as a DELETE Button, EDIT button and so forth. I want to add another button only if the exam has a certain variable set.

Record Set Example

```
| Key | ExamName    | ExamLocation | ExamDate | ExamComplete |
|-----|-------------|--------------|----------|--------------|
| 1   | Test Exam 1 | TX           | 10/2/19  | Y            |
| 2   | Test Exam 2 | SC           | 10/4/19  | Y            |
| 3   | Test Exam 3 | AL           | 10/29/19 | N            |
| 4   | Text Exam 4 | WA           | 10/22/19 | Y            |
```

so for each on of the records that have a 'Y' set for ExamComplete, I want to display a button but not for those with a 'N'

I have monkeyed with the "onCurrent" and "onLoad" event with no success.

Example CODE

```vb
If me.ExamComplete.Value = "Y" Then
    Me.BtnClickOpen.visable = TRUE
ELSE
    Me.BtnClickOpen.visable = FALSE
END IF
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: onCurrent should be replaced by Private Sub Form_Current(  )

Comment: You can't  do this with buttons, because they are not bound to a field, like a textbox. That results in all buttons behave the same if you hide one. You can use textbox with a button like color (text color = background color) and use cobditional format on it epression (' enabled = ExamComplete = "Y"' )

Comment: "no success" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Are buttons in form header section? Is ExamComplete a Yes/No field type?

Comment: @June button in continous form, modify one the others are modified too. They are just one button instance that gets repeated in details section.

Comment: Doesn't explicitly say buttons are in Detail section but inferred. If buttons are in Header, only one instance of buttons are displayed and state of BtnClickOpen will be dependent on record with focus.

Comment: Thanks, It was worth a Try. I will mark this as answered

Answer (score 1):

Place buttons in form Header section. If ExamComplete is a Yes/No field type, don't put parameter within quote marks. Regardless of field type, a one-liner is possible - for Yes/No, just reference the field.

`Me.BtnClickOpen.Visible = Me!ExamComplete`

Certainly want code in form Current event but possibly also in ExamComplete checkbox AfterUpdate.

There is only one button so VBA setting property impacts ALL instances of button - each record will display the same. It will work in Detail section but can be distracting and confusing to user with all button instances disappearing/appearing. Alternative is textbox with Conditional Formatting (no VBA) to emulate a button in Detail section. The textbox will always be visible (unless rule changes background color to match form so it blends in) and dynamically enabled/disabled individually per record.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered`Detail_Paint`event can be used for conditional format on Buttons (and other controls without`FormatConditions`property) in a continuous forms`Detail-Section`. Although you can't set the visible property, you can set the`.Transparent`property. As`Button_Click`event fires on transparent button too, you have to check in click event wether code should be executed or not.

```vb
Private Sub Detail_Paint()
  Me.BtnClickOpen.Transparent = Not Me.ExamComplete.Value = "Y"
End Sub

Private Sub BtnClickOpen_Click()
  If Me.ExamComplete.Value = "Y" Then
    ' button visible(not tranparent), execute button-click code
  Else
    'button transparent, do nothing
  End If
End Sub
```