# Checkboxes firing on all records instead of the selected record

Tags: forms, ms-access, checkbox

I'm building a form that contains a subform to list records as a datasheet.   The fields on the subform are sourced from a saved query.    To the subform, I added a checkbox control to serve as a record selector.

Here is the problem:  When I click on the checkbox of specific record on the subform, ALL the checkboxes on all the records display a check rather than just the one I clicked.  I cannot figure out what is causing this undesirable behavior.

Any insights or suggestions to fix this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkbox is unbound - in any continuous form or datasheet, unbound controls have the same value for all records (how else could they be unbound?).

You will have to add a "selector" column to the record source. Only bound controls can have different values for different records.

Comment: Got it!   I know how I can remedy this now.   Thank you.

Comment: @TomZvolensky How did you add a "selector" column to the record source? New column in table? Multiuser db?

Comment: @Andre: Binding to an expression is sufficent and with [Detail_Paint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57018157/9439330) event you should be able to set different values.with'empty`ControlSource`

Comment: @ComputerVersteher

I added a true/false column to one of the tables that comprises the view (query) on my form.   It displays as a checkbox on the form.  When the box is checked, the record is selected by a query run from a button to process that information for a specific purpose.

Comment: @TomZvolensky after Button_Click the selection is deleted (new column is set to false for whole table)? If there are multiple users , each should have its own independent selection?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a field in a table (selection-data is only temporary), you can use`clsCCRecordSelect`-Class from [SelectRecordsV2](http://www.ccedv.de/downloads/start.php?download=SelectRecordsV2.zip&lang=en).

It binds the control to an expression (calls a function in`ControlSource`that returns the value of the checkbox, stored in a collection of the class) and uses the controls`MouseDown` event to change the value (as controls bound to an expression are read-only).

That makes the selection multiuser captable and avoids creating additional selection field to tables.